# How can i sort the order of the directories inside the array?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(mainpath);
for (int x = 0; x < dirs.Length; x++)
```

When i loop over the directories i see that in dirs the directories not in order the first one is not the first one on the hard disk a lot of mess every dir is not in it's place.
I want it to be the same order as it is on the hard disk. The first one created to be the first on in dirs.

How can i do it ?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please share with us what you've tried?

Comment: Hello an thank you. I didn't try anything yet , i'm not familier with any sorting options.

Comment: `GetDirectories` uses OS order (whatever it is), there should be no differences with default unsorted list obtained via native APIs. Please clarify API you use to check "first one on the hard disk" so matching option for .Net (if one exists) can be provided.

Comment: well it sounds that you want to unsort them, because GetDirectories() will return them in alphabetically sorted order. exactly as Explorer displays directories. so what exactly you don't like about alphabetical order?

Answer (score 2):

You can sort by creation time:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(mainpath);
IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> sortedDirectories = 
    di.GetDirectories().OrderBy(c => c.CreationTime);
```

Then you can use a foreach iteration:

```
foreach(DirectoryInfo info in sortedDirectories)
{
    //access info here
}
```

Although this might not be the order you are referring to by `same order as it is on the hard disk`